# Collections.counter count dictionary values and keep other pair?

Tags: python

I'm trying to count a reoccurring dictionary, which I can do successfully with Counter, however I need to keep the second key pair in within the same dictionary.

Hopefully the sample will help:

```
>>>conns = {'circuit_type': 'MPLS', 'priority': 1}, {'circuit_type': 'MPLS', 'priority': 1}, {'circuit_type': '4G', 'priority': 4},...
>>>Counter(t['circuit_type'] for t in conns)
Counter({'MPLS': 63, 'Down': 14, '4G': 1, 'DSL': 1})
```

what I need is a list of total re-occurrences with their corresponding priories next to each other:

`[{'MPLS': 63, 'priority': 1}, {'Down': 14,'priority': 10},{'4G': 1,'priority': 3},{'DSL': 1', priority': 2}]`

or

`[{'type': 'MPLS', 'count' : 63, 'priority': 1}, {'type': 'Down', 'count' : 14, 'priority': 10}, {'type': '4G', 'count': 1,'priority': 3},{'type': 'DSL', 'count': 1, 'priority': 2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the relevant parts of each element in `conns` and use a counter on those:

```
collections.Counter(((d['circuit_type'], d['priority']) for d in conns))
```

returns

```
Counter({('4G', 4): 1, ('MPLS', 1): 2})
```

Comment: in the first brackets thats a tuple yes? using val, count is only showing the tuple. not the count as well. I tried for count, priority, total in counter: but that has failed

Comment: @AlexW sorry mis-copied from terminal: `for val, count in counter.items(): ...`

Comment: how would I access the val tuple items in the same loop? I that possible?

Comment: @AlexW using `counter.items` get you both the values and the counts for those values. Checkout [the docs for `Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @AlexW You may want to ask a new question if this format is not clear.